# nginx always sends stale index.html

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am using nginx as reverse proxy web server for a flask application. Here is my config file:

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_err.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

When I go to the root of the server, e.g. `www.myserver.com` (the nginx is listening on port 80), chrome is always using cache to get the index.html file. Looking at the nginx logs, the `GET /` isn't logged at all and my web application (`python-flask`) doesn't even get the request.

When going to `www.myserver.com/#/` the request does go through.

Any idea what is causing this issue and how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

> NGINX will not cache responses if proxy_buffering is set to off. It is on by default.

Source: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

Comment: I have added the `proxy_buffering off;` to the `location /` part but I still get the same behavior. Any other suggestion? thanks

Comment: This will force the "Cache-Control: no-cache" header, which means it will disable browser caching: `expires -1;`